# Connect to corporate wifi with personal phone - decrypt https?

Tags: encryption, tls, ios, tls-intercept

Someone asked regarding wifi yesterday but can't find the post anymore.
When connecting to corporate wifi with my personal **iPhone** for first time, I am asked to trust a "Root CA". However, I do not see the certificate under **"Certificate trust settings"** where we can see custom-root certificates. Does this mean that the wifi can not decrypt my https activity and was only used for authorization? Is there any other way to decrypt https without installing a certificate, but just clicking "trust" or is this the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Commonly used technique of HTTPS monitoring is a proxy, with certificate substitution. This proxy would terminate SSL on client's behalf, and provide another HTTPS session using it's own SSL certificate. This certificate is configured to be trusted by local domain endpoints, but won't be trusted by personal devices, unless configured separetly.
In your case, it is most likely, you have been warned about the authenticating server certificate when connected to WiFi. Upon connecting to any HTTPS site you can examine the connection certificate in use to confirm site authenticity.

Comment: Hi Grigory! Thank you for your answer. Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but does this mean that the "trust" process was just for authentication? I don't see anything under the "Certificate trust settings", meaning there is no custom-root certificate installed. How would this affect possibilities to decrypt https for full URL visibility? Can it still happen without proper installation of certificate, but just by clicking on "trust" the first time connecting to the wifi environment?

Comment: From your description you don't seem to have any additional trust except the WiFi authenticating party. You can confirm this by disconnecting and reconnecting to the same network again, and with the certificate already being trusted, you should connect without additional prompt. It is not a root certificate but a server certificate. To confirm your HTTPS connection is secure, you still need to check the connection status in browser and verify that the certificate used is issued by a well known certificate authority. That would confirm your traffic is not being intercepted by a local proxy.